# Using FB Like Button in Native iOS Swift App

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-like

Hi I am trying to make a FB Like button in my app. I have seen a lot of posts and they are old and not clear for me.

Here is what I did:

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit

class MyClass{

    @IBOutlet weak var fbLikeButton: FBSDKLikeButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.fbLikeButton.objectID = "MyPage"
      }
 }
```

In the story board I Chose `FBSDKLikeButton` as class for the button in the Identity inspector.

Now:
1. This dosent work.
2. I want to do the `FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount` if possible.

I tried to do like this without `FBSDKLikeButton` as class for the button in the Identity inspector :

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit

class MyClass{

    @IBOutlet weak var contentView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let likeControl:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
        likeControl.objectID = "MyPage"   
        likeControl.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
        likeControl.frame = CGRectMake(15, 15, 200, 40)
        likeControl.likeControlHorizontalAlignment = .Left
        self.contentView.addSubview(likeControl)
      }
 }
```

It appeared but it didnt affect number of likes.

Any clear direct solution?! All the posts are old. I hope this will be a new clear one.

Thx

Comment: read this you got your solution https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started/like-button#code

Comment: When you say "doesn't affect number of likes", do you mean it does not update the number of likes in your app after returning from the FB app where you confirm the like? If yes, have a look at this guide, you might be missing some code, especially the part in the app delegate that handles the callback from the FB app https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/getting-started#delegate

Comment: this line is not working in swift 2.2
likeControl.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
i tried "FBSDKLikeControlStyleBoxCount" as in header file 
still unidentified. Anyone clue whats happening. Why its not seeing whats in header file. are things different when using framworks